# select blank row it deselect items from listview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
int selectedRowIndex = 0;    
private void listViewUserList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(listViewUserList.SelectedIndices.Count == 0)
       return;
}
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(listViewUserList.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        listViewUserList.Items[selectedRowIndex].Selected = true;
        listViewUserList.Select();
    }
}
```

On form load I'm selecting first row in `ListView`. But when I select blank row it deselect items from `ListView`.

What should I do when click on blank row then select previously selected row? I have searched on Google but didn't find any good answers. Answers on stackoverflow only for WPF not for windows form.

Comment: In Winforms i explicitly mentioned already...

Comment: @Rahul `Page.Ispostback` doesn't do much in WinForms :)

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you are asking here. Could you rephrase your question?

Comment: @Alex 
My project is .NET/WinForms.

I have a list view which is always filled with items. I would like it to have selection always. However, if I click on an empty area below list view items, it looses selection.

Answer (score 0):

1. Save the previous index in the class.
2. If current index points to an empty string, change the selection back to previous selection using (1)
3. Then call `myListView.Select()`;

**Code:**

```
 private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if(listViewUserList.Items.Count > 0 && (String.Empty != listViewUserList.Items[selectedRowIndex].ToString() ))
     {
         listViewUserList.Items[selectedRowIndex].Selected = true;
         listViewUserList.Select();
     }
 }
```

Comment: However, if I click on an empty area below list view items, it looses selection.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adding an event handler for the `ListView`'s `MouseUp` event. If you still need the event handler for the `SelectedIndexChanged` and it's delegate method, `listViewUserList_SelectedIndexChanged`, remove from it any code that handles the item selection:

```
private void listViewUserList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // remove the 2 lines below, as the selection handling is done in the
    // MouseUp event handler

    //if(listViewUserList.SelectedIndices.Count == 0)
    //   return;

    // TODO: get the column data
}
```

Add the following event handler:

```
listViewUserList.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(this.listViewUserList_MouseUp);
```

and the following method:

```
private void listViewUserList_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (listViewUserList.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        selectedRowIndex = listViewUserList.SelectedItems[0].Index;
    }
    else
    {
        listViewUserList.Items[selectedRowIndex].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: i want listview SelectedIndexChanged  i have to get coloumn data

Comment: Alex can u please do in  SelectedIndexChanged  event

Comment: There is not enough information in the scope of a single call to `SelectedIndexChanged` to make the right selection. Even more, if the selection is changed inside this method, you'll have to make sure that you don't recursively trigger other `SelectedIndexChanged` events (basically, it means you'll have to unregister the event handler from the event at the beginning of the method and register it back at the end).